# Resharper Developer Productivity Tools Vs Other Free / Paid Tools

Tags: c#, resharper

I would need comments on code analysis / best practices tool. I mainly work only on C# for Tools Development. My Scope is limited to Windows Apps / Developing Services.

Stypecop tool suggest review comments / warnings.  For them link is provided to the URL for best practices

Resharper - Implements suggestions and changes, reduces time to make the changes manually

I find resharper useful to make the changes and saves time.

1. Is resharper best productivity tool for a intermediate C#
   developer
2. Do we have any other cheap tool which handles code changes
   / suggestions / replace suggestions for best practices than
   providing review comments only

Considering my scope (only C#, Web Forms, Web Services) I find Resharper a better option considering cost compared to CodeRush. Any suggestions / comments would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I have used CodeRush and switched then to Resharper.

I think both tools are worth every cent they cost. I can't say what tool is better, i think they have a similar feature matrix. Resharper is a bit more focussed on refactoring helpers.

Personally, i'm a bit more convinced of resharper and i really think i can't code without it any more.